# How to get the first page of a template using #switch?

Tags: mediawiki, wiki, mediawiki-templates

I recently installed MediaWiki and I have created some templates.
Now I want to create a template news that gives me only the first page, I tried with switch (in `mysite.org/wiki/Template:Pagina_principale/Vetrina`):

```
{{#switch: {{#expr: 1 + ({{CURRENTTIMESTAMP}} - 20000000000000) mod 6}}
  |1={{Vetrina/1}}
  |2={{Vetrina/2}}
  |3={{Vetrina/3}}
  |4={{Vetrina/4}}
  |5={{Vetrina/5}}
  |6={{Vetrina/6}}
  |{{Vetrina/1}}
}} · [[mywiki:Vetrina|Tutte le voci in vetrina]]<noinclude>[[Categoria:Template pagina principale|Vetrina]]</noinclude>
```

The pages `mysite.org/wiki/Template:Vetrina/1` and `mysite.org/wiki/Template:Vetrina/2`, etc are news pages.

The problem is that it gives me this error, my wiki does not recognize `#switch` and I do not understand why.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`{{#switch}}`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:ParserFunctions#.23switch) is part of [the ParserFunctions extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ParserFunctions), so you will need to install that.